# How do you use Connection Pooling with Ruby's Rest Client gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, connection-pooling, rest-client

I am using RestClient to do some communication with an API in one of my Rails apps.

I cannot figure out how to setup connection pooling with this gem.

My question is essentially:

How do i configure Rest Client to use a connection pool?

Comment: sadly, this seems to impossible right now, it's an open issue in their bug tracker: https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/issues/453#issue-124823342 (nevermind the second comment, it seems unrelated)